# c++ cannot find element is unordered_set with the same hash

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I have custom hash function for unordered_set of vectors< int >:

```
struct VectorHash {
int operator()(const vector<int> &V) const {
    int hsh=V[0] + V[1];
    return  hash<int>()(hsh);
}};
```

And for two such vectors I have the same hash equal 3:

```
vector<int> v1{2,1};
vector<int> v2{1,2};
```

But when I try to insert first vector v1 in unordered_set, and then check if I have the same vector by hash as v2 in my unordered_set I get false:

```
std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>, VectorHash> mySet;
mySet.insert(v1); 

if(mySet.find(v2) == mySet.end())
    cout << "didn't find" << endl;

Output:  "didn't find"
```

I assume that if two elements in unordered_set have the same hash then if I have v1 in my unordered_set, `find` method should return true, when I try to find v2. But it is not the case.

Could anyone explain me what is wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hash isn't everything, what you're seeing here, is a collision.

Both `std::vector<int>` have the same hash value here, but after hash is calculated, `std::unordered_map` will actually actually check for equality of elements using `operator==` to check for equality of elements, which fails in this case, and fails to find the element.

Collisions are a normal thing in HashMaps, not much you can do here without providing custom `operator==`.

Comment: `std::unordered_set` accepts a comparator as third argument, you can create one just like he did for `VectorHash` and get the result he's looking for without having to use an `unordered_map`

Answer (score 3):

> I assume that if two elements in unordered_set have the same hash then if I have v1 in my unordered_set, find method should return true, when I try to find v2.

That assumption is incorrect, same hash doesn't mean objects are equal.

[`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) uses the equality predicate to determine key equality (by default `std::equal_to`).

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to want unique identifiers but not automatically compare values, you could use an `(unordered_)map<int, vector<int>>` and use that VectorHash function to generate the int key:

```
unordered_map<int, vector<int>> map;

int key=V[0] + V[1]
map[key] = V;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide a comparator to the `unordered_set` as well if you want the two elements to match, you can do something along the lines of this:

```
struct VectorComparator {
  bool operator()(const std::vector<int> & obj1, const std::vector<int> & obj2) const
  {
    if ((obj1[0] + obj1[1]) == (obj2[0] + obj2[1]))
      return true;
    return false;
  }
};
```

and create your `unordered_set` like this

`std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>, VectorHash, VectorComparator> mySet;`

Then you should get the result you are expecting